# Php script does not connect to MySQL (Vagrant VM)

Tags: mysql, vagrant

I need help for a php script to connect to mysql database.

I have installed *VirtulaBox* and *Vagrant* and setup an Ubuntu 16.04 server. On the server I have installed *apache2*, *php7.0* and *mariadb*.

---

I have created a second user of mysql (beside the root one) and I can connect on the command line to mysql with both the root and the new user.

---

I have uploaded a small test app on the server and all went good until the application needs to connect to the database. I receive the error message below:

> "Could not connect to MySql: Access denied for user
>   'Lucian'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

At the level of mysql I have two users: the **root** and **lucian**. I can connect to both of them from the command line. The user **lucian@localhost** is the user used to ssh in to the server from Vagrant based on public/private keys pair.

---

It seems like the script is trying to connect to mysql using the vagrant user. One more thing is, if I try to connect in terminal just with the command *mysql -p* i receive similar error message (even if I use the password for the root user). I have tried to establish a connection from PHPStorm, but i have failed, too. 
The php script is the following:

```
<?php  DEFINE('DB_USER', 'lucian');  DEFINE('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxx'); DEFINE('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'); DEFINE('DB_NAME', 'portal');

$dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) OR die ('Could not connect to MySql: '. mysqli_connect_error() );
```

---

*What is puzzling me is why the script (which is located on the server) does not use the correct credentials that work from the command line?* **Any help is appreciated! Thanks!**

Comment: Have you added `lucian` as a user in MySQL, or in the Linux installation? The MySQL users are *not* the same as the system user you use for login. Also, try to use `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` as DB_HOST.

Comment: I have added lucian as user (as % any host) in MySQL and works fine in the command line. I have tried with _localhost_, but I have the same error.

Comment: Solved it. It was a stupid mistake for my part! I have referenced  the credentials from a wrong file and of course that any changes made to it did not have any result. Spent 4-5 hours until I have realized. Everything is fine now and I have connected also from PhpStorm. Thanks for your help!